# Issue with using font with @font-face declaration and in general with applications

Tags: css, fonts, adobe-illustrator

```
@font-face {
    font-family: iconFont;
    src: local(iconFont), url('fonts/iconFont.ttf') format('opentype');
}
```

The font file is not corrupt and installs fine in OSX etc. letting me preview it. But it won't render anything when I try to use it on a web page or even if I select it in illustrator it just switches to another font if I touch any key.

The font is for 'regular' and I have tried other options, but it won't work. Have tried typing with caps on/off etc. Using numpad, nothing. Have re-installed it and made sure there are no duplicates. It also won't work in Windows. Not sure if I need to change my css somehow or the fault lays with the font.

Here's a link to the font for anyone wanting to try. It's a bunch of metro icons. http://www2.zippyshare.com/v/23494573/file.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but this is the CSS I use, and it works fine. The webfonts directory is in the same directory as the css file, and includes three file types: .eot .ttf .woff

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AvenirLT-Book';
    src: url('webfonts/25EE2B_0_0.eot');
    src: url('webfonts/25EE2B_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('webfonts/25EE2B_0_0.woff') format('woff'), url('webfonts/25EE2B_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

a typical class decleration:

```
.AvenirLT-Book {
    font-family: AvenirLT-Book;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

perhaps you need to change the format to `('truetype')` instead of `('opentype')` ?

Comment: nope, still no go. I get a feeling there's something wrong with the font file. It validates and previews fine, but for some strange reason when I try to type anything using it nothing shows up, even in application like illustrator.

Comment: yeah sounds like it. I guess you can try with a different font and see if the same thing happens...